# Eclipse: view a document using custom spacing, save using the file's spacing

Tags: eclipse

I have a silly use case for eclipse:

At work, they use 2 spaces for a tab character. Indentation looks really squashed and I'm finding it obstructs readability.

Now, I can't set Eclipse to use 4 spaces for a tab as it'll edit any files I change, and obviously don't want to violate the coding standards.

So, can I have a custom view onto my document, with saving maintaining the original spacing?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>(Not exactly an "eclipse" answer, but it can work)</sup>
Combine your source code with a SCM like git, where you can define a [custom filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2316728#2316728) with a smudge/clean process:

[image]

Each time you checkout and fill your working directory, all .java files will be written with 4 spaces.
But each time you commit them, they will be stored with 2 spaces.

Then, whatever current VCS you are using (SVN, Perforce, ...) will take those (git) commit files and will commit them in turn (but with the right format).
Since you can [embed a Git repo inside any workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984390/tracking-daily-changes-as-a-peon-in-a-clearcase-shop/984877#984877) of any other central VCS, this can be easy to setup.