# Eclipse: Configure tab view

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to configure Eclipse to not use white spaces, BUT to still only indent 2,3,? spaces instead of the standard 4?  I don't want to move to white spaces instead of tabbing, because I believe this is a personal choice for the person working on the project.

The closest answer I've seen is https://stackoverflow.com/a/2477132/5525659

It works, but I'm wondering if there is a better/easier way if people are sharing files different ways?

Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the ***displayed tab width*** in ***Window > Preferences: General > Editors > Text Editors***.

In **Java**, the displayed tab width can be set in the formatter profile: ***Window > Preferences: Java > Code Style > Formatter***, in the profile dialog, in the ***Indentation* tab**, in the field ***Tab size***.

Other editors might use the text editors preferences or have their own preferences.

Comment: Thank you.  That's what I was looking for.  It appears to work for some files, but not all, which I am guessing because those file types have different default tab settings that I will need to go in and override... or just deal with.