# Code Review - Clearcase - How to get a list of files a user modified since another label?

Tags: diff, clearcase, cleartool

I'd like to create a dynamic view that only shows the files a user created/modified for a particular label.

Right now, I am listing all of the files in the label and comparing that with the previous label.

If I have to use cleartool to find the files, that is fine with me.  I'd like the process to be more automated than it currently is.

Another option too is, can I simply see the diffs for a particular user?  That way, I am more likely to understand the file's history.  If a developer had attempted something one way and found that didn't work, it might be helpful to see that trial and error.

config spec:

```
#element * REL_2010.2.2.006
element * .../pgh_rel_4.0.0_dot_rel/{created_by(pp50773)&&lbtype(REL_2010.2.2.006)}

# first stop rule
element -directory * .../pgh_rel_4.0.0_dot_rel/{lbtype(REL_2010.2.2.006)}
# second stop rule
element -directory * main/LATEST
```

This config spec doesn't fetch my changes - It fetches empty directories.  It is also important to note that while I made the changes to the actual file, another guy is responsible for applying the label weekly.  So, if it goes by whose name is on the label, that won't work.

If I remove the created_by constraint, it works fine listing all of the changes for the label, but I want only files in that label for a given user.

Walter

Comment: That is strange: can you see, when you remove the filter 'created-by', one version tree of one of the files displayed? Does the user who apply the label also create a new version? Or is the version labelled (by whoever) created by you?

Comment: Yes, if I remove the filter, I see all the files in that particular label.  If I use the userId for the guy that applied the labels, I see just the files he actually checked in.

Comment: @Walter: that means it didn't just apply the label. He checked out/checked-in the files, creating new versions before doing the 'mklabel'

Comment: Ah, the problem was the user id is case sensitive and apparently my user id is in upper case.  This works great.

Comment: @VonC This doesn't work entirely for me.  I believe it is pulling some files that were created in a previous release rather than pulling files that were modified for this label.

Comment: @Walter: what does "`cleartool ls`" in the parent directory returns for those files? (in other word, what is the selection rule used for those incorrect versions?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the **[version selector rules](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/version_selector.htm)**, you can do that, but I would recommend:

- 2 dynamic views (easy to setup and refresh, since their content is not downloaded on your hard drive, but accessed through the network)

  - one one for one label
  - one for the other
- to not forget to add stop rules for directories (if directories are not created by your user, they won't be selected, meaning your view won't be able to select *any* version within it.

The config spec for one of those view would be something like:

```
element * .../MyBranch/{created_by(myuser)&&lbtype(MY_LABEL)}
# first stop rule
element -directory * .../MyBranch/LATEST
# second stop rule
element -directory * main/LATEST
```

When you have two views correctly configured, you can compare their content with a [tool like WinMerge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413649/how-to-diff-merge-changes-to-a-deployment-project-file/417962#417962).

Comment: I updated my question to include my updated config spec, it dies on the created_by clause.

Comment: @Walter: I was seeing that while you were typing your comment;). By "die" you mean "empty directories", not "error message", right?

Comment: correct.  It lets me use that config spec and I see directories, but they're all empty.